# Tomcat Embedded - ClassNotFoundException: JspServlet

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

i want to use Tomcat to test some web services (using maven). The Tomcat is running with maven @ test. When i try to deploy my war, i directly get a ClassNotFoundException for JspServlet. The jasper jars are in the classpath and i debugged through the code. Try to load the class with loadClass() -> get this error, Class.forName() is working...

Maybe someone has an idea

My test Class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    wsdlURL = new URL(address + "?wsdl");

    String appBase = "./target";
    tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port")));
    tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);

    StandardServer server = (StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
    AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
    server.addLifecycleListener(listener);

    Context app = tomcat.addWebapp("/service", warFile.getAbsolutePath());
    app.addSecurityRole("AllRole");
    tomcat.start();
}
```

Parts of my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>warFile</name>
                        <value>${project.build.finalName}</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>port</name>
                        <value>9101</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-web-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
[...]

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I tried tomcat version 7 and 8.

Maybe someone has an idea why the jasper package is ignored?

Comment: Put the JSP related jars in your tomcat lib directory and change the scope to "provided".

Comment: It's Tomcat Embedded, i have no lib folder. But as i wrote, i checked teh classpath and the jar is inside.

Comment: Right, have a look [here](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath). Pretty good explanation of how embedded tomcat handles classpaths.